# Implementing Error Handling and Abort Mechanism in Kafka Consumer with Conditional Retry Logic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Spring for Apache Kafka has a default mechanism of 10 attempts after an error is thrown from a consumed message. I want this mechanism to remain in place, but I also want a way to stop it if the error thrown is the `AbortException.class` type.

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(@NotNull ConsumerRecord<String, Object> message) throws IOException {
    ...
    doSomething();
}
```

If `doSomething()` throws the `AbortException` exception, I want to prevent any further retries and abort the processing of this consumed message.

```java
@Bean
public DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    BackOff fixedBackOff = new FixedBackOff(interval, maxAttempts);
    return new DefaultErrorHandler((consumerRecord, exception) -> log.error("Error while processing: {}, exception: {}", consumerRecord.topic(), exception.getClass()), fixedBackOff);
}
```

This handler only runs when all attempts are exhausted and the `doSomething()` method couldn't be executed successfully. I want something that runs after every attempt to check which exception is thrown, and if it's an `AbortException`, abort the remaining retries.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh).

and the javadocs

```java
/**
 * Add exception types to the default list. By default, the following exceptions will
 * not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried, unless {@link #defaultFalse()} has been called.
 * @param exceptionTypes the exception types.
 * @see #removeClassification(Class)
 * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
 */
public final void addNotRetryableExceptions(Class<? extends Exception>... exceptionTypes) {
```

You can also make it even more fine-grained...

```java
/**
 * Set a function to dynamically determine the {@link BackOff} to use, based on the
 * consumer record and/or exception. If null is returned, the default BackOff will be
 * used.
 * @param backOffFunction the function.
 * @since 2.6
 */
public void setBackOffFunction(BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, BackOff> backOffFunction) {
```

on the `DefaultErrorHandler`.